# How to repeat the same function in a matrix, changing a parameter of the function

Tags: r, loops

I am learning to generate loops. I have this function from "betapart" package:

```
beta.diversity <- beta.sample(x, index.family="Sorensen", sites= n, samples= n)
```

where

**x**: data frame, where rows are sites and columns are species.

**index.family:**  family of dissimilarity indices, partial match of "sorensen" or "jaccard".

**sites:** number of sites for which multiple-site dissimilarities will be computed. If not specified, default is all sites.
**samples:** number of repetitions. If not specified, default is 1.

What I need is to run the **same function** in a matrix, but **increasing** the sites one at a time (some matrix have 1000 sites)

I thought that with the "lapply" function it might work, but I can't think of how.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post example data for a more specific answer. Are you working with one matrix, i.e., each iteration of the loop should include an increasing number of columns? Or do you have multiple matrices? A general answer is to do this:  `for(nsites in 1:length(sites)){beta.diversity <- beta.sample(x, index.family="Sorensen", sites= nsites, samples= n)}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is only one matrix where columns are species and rows are site. What the function does is take a specific number of sites of the matrix (**sites** parameter of the function) and extract the beta diversity as many times the "**samples**" parameter says. What I need is run the function several times, changing the number of sites. If I do manually, shows like this

Comment: beta.den.010<-beta.sample(ma_bb.den, index.family="sorensen", sites = 10, samples = 1000)

beta.den.010<-beta.sample(ma_bb.den, index.family="sorensen", sites = 20, samples = 1000)

beta.den.030<-beta.sample(ma_bb.den, index.family="sorensen", sites = 30, samples = 1000)

beta.den.040<-beta.sample(ma_bb.den, index.family="sorensen", sites = 40, samples = 1000)

beta.den.050<-beta.sample(ma_bb.den, index.family="sorensen", sites = 50, samples = 1000)


and so on from ten to ten or twenty to twenty, which is very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how a generic loop works:

```
fruits <- c("apple", "peach", "pear")

# Use the elements in a vector directly
for(fruit in fruits){
  print(fruit)
}

# You can also use the index of each element
for(i in 1:length(fruits)){
  print(fruits[i])
}
```

See how a generic lapply works:

```
lapply(fruits, print)
```

---

Get example data from the `betapart` package:

```
library(betapart)

data(bbsData)
dat <- bbs2000[,1:10]
```

With a loop:

```
# Retain results
results <- list()

# Loop over each number of sites
allnsites = c(2:10)

for(i in 1:length(allnsites)){
  beta.diversity <- beta.sample(dat, index.family="sorensen", sites= allnsites[i], samples= 1)
  # Report number of sites in each iteration
  beta.diversity$sites <- allnsites[i]
  results[[i]] <- beta.diversity
}
```

With `lapply()`:

```
lapply(allnsites, FUN = beta.sample, x = dat, index.family = "sorensen", samples = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much !. I added some other things, but it is what I needed.

Comment: Ok great, glad this helped! I updated my answer to include an example using `lapply()` too, fyi. Good luck